How does an application sign a UserOperation given that each SCA provider has their own auth
In the days of EOAs, signing a transaction was trivially done by making a JS call which invoked a browser extension which has access to various account's private keys.
In the age of Account Abstraction, each Smart Contract Account wallet provider's implementation can do their own thing with respect to checking the signature of a UserOperation.
This means that applications must generate the signature accordingly.
Presumably, this means using the provided SDK. For example, Coinbase checks a WebAuthn challenge and presumably has a specific credential ID to choose the key pair.
All this implies that onchain applications must now reference the SDKs of every single SCA provider in the world, and keep an eye on new ones, in order to sign UserOperations.
And that means keeping a map of user<->SCA_provider within your app so you can route your users to the appropriate code for signing.
And this feels like SCA providers will become points of high-dependency and concentration.
Am I right? Or have I got myself in a muddle? Or perhaps there's a mega signing SDK someone's maintaining?

I found this topic interesting. In my opinion, a dapp might choose an SCA provider to enhance UX by creating a new SCA for users.
However, this could lead to a problem where a user in one dapp cannot use the SCA created by another dapp. A solution to this issue might be offered by a browser extension which can import SCAs into the wallet and provide an ERC6963 injected provider as before.
In this case, the dapp requests a normal transaction from the wallet, which the extension converts into a userOp before sending it to the bundler.
I found a project working on this: https://github.com/pilagod/waallet-extension

Thanks for this, I appreciate it. Something doesn't feel right about AA. We've shifted and hidden the need for a private key to some place that the user doesn't understand, and is hard for devs, tbh. So a person may lose access to their wallet if they leave their Chrome or Apple garden, and they won't know why. And we've anointed new gatekeepers via the SCA providers. Was teaching people to really look after a secret so hard? I wonder if AA was a turning point.
